How do you see that the Wannier functions are localized on ion sites?
In Condensed Matter Field Theory by Altland and Simons, when discussing the tight-binding approximation for a lattice system with a periodic potential, they define the Wannier states as follows:
$$
|\psi_{\mathbf{R}n}\rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}^{\text{B.Z.}} e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{R}}|\psi_{\mathbf{k}n\rangle},
$$
where $\mathbf{R}$ is some lattice center and $|\psi_{\mathbf{k}n}\rangle$ is a Bloch vector with $n$ labeling the energy band and $\mathbf{k}$ labeling the crystal momentum. They then say that, in the limit of vanishingly weak interatomic overlap, the Wannier function converges on the $n$th orbital of an isolated atom centered at the coordinate $\mathbf{R}$. I am interpreting this as the statement that the Wannier functions are localized about the ion center $\mathbf{R}$.
My question is, how do I see that this is the case (or, if my interpretation is wrong, what is the correct interpretation and how do I see that the correct interpretation is true)? Intuitively, when $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{R}$, the phases cancel out so $\psi_{\mathbf{R}n}(x)$ is a sum of energy eigenstates $u_{\mathbf{k}n}(\mathbf{R})$, and I was thinking that maybe there is some type of constructive interference that occurs and similarly, there is destructive interference when you go away from $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{R}$. However, the eigenstates are complex in general, so it's  not clear to me that this interference argument is correct.

See e.g. Wikipedia.
